# opendds video streaming using opencv

Tags: opencv, opendds

i have a question of this. I am using opendds to stream video using opencv.
In opendds i used data type CORBA::OctetSeq data for mat data.

I have successed using tao_idl and opendds_idl to make several files and now i'm trying to make publisher.cpp

Do you know how to put the mat type data to OctetSeq data??

I've tried like this.

...
`Mat img`
`img = Mat::zeros(480,640, CV_8UC1)`
`cap >> img`
`message.data = img`
...

the error says that the operator don't work

if i set `message.data = img.data` it says that "error: invalid conversion from 'uchar' to 'CORBA::ULong'

please help this project is unit Feb :(

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/issues/2371 for the answer of this question.